# Configuring Glassfish 3.1.2 Server to allow PUT, DELETE

Tags: web-services, configuration, glassfish-3, restful-authentication

I am having a problem configuring my Glassfish 3.1.2 Server to allow PUT, DELETE request for a RESTful webservice created with the Netbeans "Create new RESTful webservice from Database" wizard. Weirdly, I managed to get one webservice working the others not. Can anyone shed some light on where/how I configure this ?

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
Allow: GET,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1153
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 18:35:05 GMT
```

The request header that works is as follows:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:133
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=b8ec1fb7ae9de4b5536363f4041d; JSESSIONID=b80bb2fbf45363cfe1b61b625890; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:configurations:server-config:networkConfig:networkListeners:http-listener-2
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/mtpStories/faces/index.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

This is the request that is failing (a different webservice) :

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:88
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=ba3ad55776f2c7ea35f6dcbe56d2; JSESSIONID=b9fe5da81c67a083beb2001a6dbf; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:configurations:default-config:httpService:httpListeners:http-listener-2
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/mtpUsers/faces/index_users.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your web.xml. Any **<security-constraint>** definitions? e.g.

```
   <security-constraint>
        ...
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/mtpStories/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        ....
   </security-constraint>
```

Comment: I removed all security constraints and PUT does not work even if I add it as an http-method

Comment: Do you have any filters defined that might modify HTTP headers?